# jQuery .css() does not update element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
function createList() {
var list = '';
var listID;
$.each(obj_JSON.colors, function(index, value) {
    listID = "clr_" + index;
    list = list + "<div id=" + listID + " alt='" + obj_JSON.colors[index].name + "'></div>"
    clrList.html(list);
    updateListColours(listID);
});
```

}

```
function updateListColours(x) {
    $('#' + x).css({"background-color":"rgb(255, 0, 0)", "height":"25px", "width":"25px"});
}
```

When I watch it get created. The first div gets the style applied to it. Then the second gets created and the style is wiped from the first div and applied to the second and it goes on until the list is complete...

Why is this happening and how can I apply the style to each div? *Expecting answer that shows i've done something really stupid as usual*

Comment: return the updateListColurs(listID)

Comment: Ensure that `x` is the correct id selector value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because this line `clrList.html(list);`, you are removing the previous element then add new created.

Instead, do it with:

```
$.each(obj_JSON.colors, function(index, value) {
    listID = "clr_" + index;
    list = "<div id=" + listID + " alt='" + obj_JSON.colors[index].name + "'></div>"
    clrList.append(list);
    updateListColours(listID);
});
```

Comment: ahhh I see! Thank you! I will run the css apply to all of the list after the creation is completed. Haha I knew it was stupid afterall. Thank you! (will tick when timer goes).

Answer (score 0):

There's a much easier solution:

```
function createList() {
    $.each(obj_JSON.colors, function() {
        var d = document.createElement('div');
        d.setAttribute("alt",this.name);
        d.className = "listcolour";
        clrList.appendChild(d);
        // ^ assumes `clrList` is a DOM node, not a jQuery object
    });
}
```

And CSS:

```css
.listcolour {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

Comment: I couldn't use this method because the list items will have different colours - they are all red at the moment because I was just trying to get it to work at a more basic level. But thanks for the input!

Comment: Well, you can use the class for the size, then use `d.style.backgroundColor = 'whatever';` as well. The point is, sometimes [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) is a lot simpler ;)